# Geom Histogram of two variables with different data types RStudio

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-histogram

I am trying to do a very simple geom plot but it is becoming complex due to following reasons. I have two variables **Date** and **Condition**. Their data type is *Date* and *Char* respectively. Following data exist in it.

| Date | Condition |
| --- | --- |
| 2015-11-26 | zoo1 |
| 2022-01-14 | K621 |
| 2020-01-14 | K20 |
| 2021-01-14 | G341 |
| 2025-01-14 | F21 |
| 2025-01-14 | G309 D |

I have total 83742 entries for the above example table. I am trying to find how much are the total **MAIN** entries by each **year** and by each **month**. i-e, I want to generate two separate graphs ***by Month*** and ***by Year*** which can show the total number of conditions by each month or by each year.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use the `lubridate` library's `round_date()` function for this type of problem:

```
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
  mutate(YearMonth=round_date(Date, "month"),
         Year=round_date(Date, "year")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=YearMonth, fill=Condition))+
  geom_bar()

df %>% 
    mutate(YearMonth=round_date(Date, "month"),
           Year=round_date(Date, "year")) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=Year, fill=Condition)) +
    geom_bar() +
    scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%Y")
```